# C++ component performance is down after update Windows 10 1903

Tags: c++, windows, performance, windows-10

I created some programs which component of Excel.
However, I updated Windows 10 1803 to 1809 or 1903. 
The Performance of this component is 30% down compare before updated.

the Programing language is C++ and I found here which down of performance.

```
Excel::_ApplicationPtr      pExcel
pExcel.CreateInstance (__uuidof (Excel::Application));
pWorkBooks = pExcel->GetWorkbooks();
pWorkBooks = WorkBooks->Open( iExcelPath.ConvertToChar() );
```

Please anyone help.
Thanks regard.

Comment: You should report this to Microsoft, not much StackOverflow can do about this.

Comment: Thanks Botje, We reported this issue Microsoft Support.
And We got answer that reinstall of office.
I try to this method.  Thanks your reply.